# Accessing cmd prompt in remote machine using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

How to access Command Prompt in remote machine using VBScript?
We are in process of creating a tool to fetch component services and its status on remote machines.
Currently we are able to achieve this in our local machine by using the below code:

```
Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set getvalue=objShell.Exec("cmd.exe /C sc queryex type= service state= all")
Do
    output = getvalue.StdOut.ReadLine
    MsgBox output
Loop While getvalue.StdOut.AtEndOfStream = False
```

But we need to achieve the same in remote machine.

Comment: Type `sc /?` and you'll see `sc` can do that. Also it is bizzare that you shell to users commands to program. See proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\127.0.0.1\root\cimv2")

Set config = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Service")
For Each thing in Config
        Msgbox thing.Caption
Next
```

Is how we query services in vbscript. These are the properties available. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If I need to get the same information from a remote machine, which part of the code needs to be changed and how?

Comment: The network address (127.0.0.1 above). It can be a server name without leading slashes or an IP address.